# Daily voting limit

Tags: discussion, voting

Today i saw the Yellow box started to appear to say "Daily voting limit reached". 
I just saw in some earlier question that daily voting limit is 40. But then i saw that my actual votes for today are only 38 (not 40).

I am just curious:

Are there any other rules associated to it?

Answer (score 4):

Originally you were restricted to 30 votes per day. These votes could be distributed between questions and answers in any ratio.

To encourage voting on questions an extra 10, question only votes were introduced taking the total to 40. However, because they are question only votes if you have voted on answers and then start voting on questions you can't always get to the full 40 votes.

There are posts on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) that explain this a lot better.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached & http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits are the relevant MSO posts...